# Как в Битрикс правильно получить активные элементы инфоблока, которые не имеют вхождения в разделы?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно получить список товаров, которые не относятся к разделам, когда поле IBLOCK_SECTION не заполнено (содержит пустой массив).
Как правильно это сделать?

```
$iblock_catalog = \Bitrix\Iblock\Iblock::wakeUp(4);
$params = array(
        'filter' => array(
            '=ACTIVE' => 'Y',
            'IBLOCK_SECTION' => 'ТУТ КАКОЕ-ТО НУЖНОЕ УСЛОВИЕ?'
    ),
        'select' => ['ID', 'IBLOCK_ID', 'XML_ID', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']
    );
try {
    $elements = $iblock_catalog->getEntityDataClass()::getList($params)->fetchCollection();
}
catch($e){
    die($e);
}
```

Comment: ```'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID' => false```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это в документации к старому методу [CIBlockElement::GetList()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php) можно прочесть:

> **SECTION_ID** - по родительской группе. Если значение фильтра false, "" или 0, то будут выбраны элементы не привязанные ни к каким разделам. Иначе будут выбраны элементы привязанные к заданному разделу. Значением фильтра может быть и массив. В этом случае будут выбраны элементы привязанные хотя бы к одному из разделов указанных в фильтре. Возможно указание отрицания "!". В этом случае условие будет инвертировано;

Таким образом Вам надо указать:

```
'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID' => false,
```